# Having difficulty editing datagridview. How do i make it editable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datagridview

I've linked a combobox to the datagridview and its working perfectly. However, I need to make the datagridview editable but I can't enter anything into the datagridview. **ReadOnly is off/false.** I've tried to use a cellvaluechanged event when the value of the datagridview, but first I need to get the cell to change. How do I make the datagridview editable through linq to entity?

```
private void editDataGridView_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    editDataGridView.CellValueChanged 
      += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(editDataGridView_CellValueChanged);
}

private void editDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
     MessageBox.Show("Cell Changed"); 
}
```

This is where I link the combobox and the datagridview

```
private void cboeCID_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var CID = Convert.ToInt32(cboeCID.Text);

     using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
     {
         var course = from c in db.Student_Course where c.CID == CID select new {
               SID = c.SID,
                Mark = c.Mark};
                editDataGridView.DataSource = course.ToList();
       }
 }
```

Comment: snippet code is not working

Comment: Have you [specified an EditMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yztkd864(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @stuartd EditonKeystroke, but I can't even type in the cells even though the datagridview's readonly property is set to false.

Comment: You shouldn't add another event handler on each cellcontentclick..Set is once on Form constructor! And you should not use MessageBox for debugging as it fouls up focus.. Use Console.WriteLine instead! That being said I'm not sure why you can't write into the cells; can you set the DataSource to null and test if that changes matters..?

Comment: @TaW It works when I don't link the combobox to the datagridview but when I do its no longer editable. But the combobox is used to display the relevant data onto the datagridview.

Comment: Hm. In addition to the DGV not being readonly: 1) What is its DataGridViewEditMode ? Also: 2) Are the columns readonly? Also: 3) Is the Datasource readonly?

Comment: @TaW The datasource. That might be it! Is there a way around it?

Comment: According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5527c78-9c97-4535-865f-07b50f68a888/how-to-make-datagridview-editable-when-binding-with-linq?forum=csharpgeneral) the problem is that anonymous types are read-only. It recommends creating a class..

Comment: @TaW so would the class contain just public int CID public int SID public int Mark?

Comment: Indeed, see my answer. Just tested it and it does make the difference here!

Comment: @TaW OMG IT WORKS NOW. WORDS CANNOT DESCRIBE HOW MUCH I APPRECIATE YOU NOW :D

Comment: @TaW chuck it in an answer and i'll give you an upvote haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5527c78-9c97-4535-865f-07b50f68a888/how-to-make-datagridview-editable-when-binding-with-linq?forum=csharpgeneral): The problem is with the [**anonymous type**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you are selecting.

> Anonymous types contain one or more public read-only properties.

So being read-only is carried over into the result set and then into the DGV..

You need to select into a **class**, even if it is no more than a dummy for just this purpose..

```
class dummy
{
    public integer SID { get; set; }
    public integer Mark { get; set; }

    public dummy() { }
    public dummy(integer w, integer p) { SID = s;  Mark = m; }
}
```

Insert you own datatypes! Pick a less lackluster name ;-)

Now you can change the select..:

```
     var course = from c in db.Student_Course where c.CID == CID select new dummy
     {
         SID = c.SID,
         Mark = c.Mark
      };

     editDataGridView.DataSource = course.ToList();
```

..and voilà: The `DataGridView` is editatable..

Comment: The edits won't save back onto the database, I tried using db.SaveChanges() but that doesn't work.

Comment: I tested without EF; is SID the pk? Are all not-null fields aboard?  In normal ADO it usually involves preparing update commends; here I don't know. Can you check the state of the data? - Issues with saving back the data are another,  new question (after some research).

Comment: Since I don't use EF could you tell me what resulting type `var course` is? (Hover over it with the cursor and intellisense will know!)

Comment: yes, but which type is the var?? `EnumerableRowCollection<dummy>`?

Comment: it's an interface type

Comment: You may want to add the __exact__ type to the new question! (Does it really just say `Interface`?)